# View.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE) does not work for animated view

Tags: android

I have an activity that (when started) shows some coachmark views (All ImageButtons) on screen that indicate how the app should be used (function of certain buttons, swipe behaviour, etc). A fade out animation is associated with each of these views that triggers after some predefined interval. This works as expected. However, I would like those marks to disappear earlier if the user interacts with the activity in a certain way. When these actions are triggered I cancel the animations and call`setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);` on the coachmark views. However, the visibility of the view does not change. I have experimented with other techniques - removing the view from the parent and setting alpha to 0 and these work fine but altering view visibility does nothing.

The code that sets up the coachmark looks as follows:

```
private void animateCoachmark(int id) {
    AlphaAnimation animation = new AlphaAnimation(1.0f, 0.0f);
    final View view = findViewById(id);
    animation.setStartOffset(10000);
    animation.setDuration(500);
    animation.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListenerBase(null) {
      @Override
      public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
      }
    });
    view.startAnimation(animation);
    coachmarkViews.add(view);
  }
```

The problematic code to change visiblity:

```
for (final View coachmarkView : coachmarkViews) {
  Animation animation = coachmarkView.getAnimation();
  if (animation != null) {
    animation.cancel();
  }
  coachmarkView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
```

Answer (score 15):

This issue seems to be that changes to visibility are not honoured as long as an animation is associated with a view even if the animation has been cancelled. Altering my cleanup code to first set the animation on the view to null allows the view to disappear as expected.

```
for (final View coachmarkView : coachmarkViews) {
  Animation animation = coachmarkView.getAnimation();
  if (animation != null) {
    animation.cancel();
    coachmarkView.setAnimation(null);
  }
  coachmarkView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
```

Comment: If you make views visibility to GONE  then even animation is associated with the view, it will not be visible on UI.