# How to set element invisible with animation?

Tags: android, animation

I have this toggle button that when it is on, calls an animation method that sets several elements visible. But when I turn it off, the elements remain visible, although the opposite instruction. How can I make them disapear with the same logic? Do I have to create another method? Thanks, here's the code:

```
 drum.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {
                key1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                key1.startAnimation(fadeInAnimation());

                key2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                key2.startAnimation(fadeInAnimation());

                key3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                key3.startAnimation(fadeInAnimation());


                rocking.setLooping(true);
                rocking.start();

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Rock and Rolling!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                rocking.setLooping(false);
                key1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);// These instrucions are ignored...
                key2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                key3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Can't keep up? Try the tamborine!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        }
    });
```

And the animation method:

```
private Animation fadeInAnimation() {
Animation animation = new AlphaAnimation(0f, 1.0f);
animation.setDuration(1000); 
animation.setFillEnabled(true);
animation.setFillAfter(true);
return animation;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the fadeInAnimation and pass a boolean argument, if true do fade-In animation else fade-out animation. Code sample is given below. Usage fadeAnimation(true) for fadeIn animation and fadeAnimation(false) for fadeOut animation. Hope this helps.

```
private Animation fadeAnimation(boolean fadeIn) {

 Animation animation = null;
 if(fadeIn)
    animation = new AlphaAnimation(0f, 1.0f);
 else
    animation = new AlphaAnimation(1.0f, 0f);
 animation.setDuration(1000); 
 animation.setFillEnabled(true);
 animation.setFillAfter(true);
 return animation;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Checkout below code**

```
viewObject.animate()
            .alpha(0.0f)
            .setStartDelay(10000)
            .setDuration(2000)
            .setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                    super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
                    // do your stuff if any, after animation ends
                }
            }).start();
```

Answer (score 0):

possible duplicate of [View.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE) does not work for animated view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23958481/view-setvisibilityview-invisible-does-not-work-for-animated-view][1]). visibility are not honoured as long as an animation is  performed even though  animation is cancelled